# Form break in foreach loop in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter, foreach

Just consider I have 30 questions in my database. I'm doing Foreach to display all questions, so it's displaying all questions in one form page 
Example:-

```
    1 Question...
      answer(textarea)
    2 Question...
      answer(textarea)
    .
    .
    .
   30 Question...
      answer(textarea)
```

Now I want to show 10 questions per page with **NEXT** button at the END of 30th Question will have **SUBMIT** Button. So that I can insert post values into database.

How can I make this ? 
Is there any jquery plugin or I do manually ?
Please Suggested I appreciate your answer

Comment: can you make an attempt at solving the problem and then post the code please?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the idea here is loop everything to the page in one go, though wrap every 10 questions in a div with an class, making sure to add style:hidden to the all but the first.

Then you can add buttons below to just show then hide the divs one after the other.

So something like this?

```
    <form class="" action="index.php" method="post">
            <?php $i = 0; ?>
            <?php foreach ($questions as $q): ?>
                <?php if (($i % 10) == 0): //Multipal of 10 ?>
                    <?php if ($i == 0): ?>
                        <div class="page">
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <div class="page" style="display:none;">
                    <?php endif; ?>

                <?php endif; ?>

                <label for="<?=$q?>">Label: <?=$q?></label><input type="text" name="<?=$q?>"><br/>

                <?php $i++; ?>
                <?php if (($i % 10) == 0): ?>
                    <?php if (count($questions) != $i): ?>
                        <button type="button" class="next-page">Next</button>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <input type="submit" name="name" value="Submit">
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php else: ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

            <?php endforeach; ?>


    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.next-page').on('click', function(){
            var currentPage = $('.page');
            currentPage.first().hide();
            currentPage.first().next().show();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Your code is working. but only 0 to 10 and 10 to 20. it doesn't have continues flow.

Comment: I couldn't spend to much time on it, it was just to help point you in the right direction

Comment: I appreciate your time and solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use a page number with you request.

1 st page -> you send the pagenum as 1.
so you limit the records by `LIMIT (pagenum * 10) 10` 
- which is `LIMIT 10 10`

2nd page -> you only change the page num to 2.
so you limit the records by `LIMIT (pagenum * 10) 10` 
- which is `LIMIT 20 10`

This is just an idea which you could implement only with php. there could be several other solutions.

Comment: Yes, we can achieve this through query. but my scenario it's not possible

Comment: In your case, you get all the records and display them as 10 per page?

Comment: try this: https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html. Its easy and this is what you need!

Comment: I want to display form. so that user can give input not datatables

Comment: So can't you add a `textarea` inside a `<td>`?

Datatables ONLY does pagination for you.

Comment: It's not only textarea, for example, this small HTML form

Comment: `<table>` `<form>` `<td>` `<textarea>` they all are HTML tags dude!!!! You can play with them. I don't understand why you can't put the building blocks together!!!!

Comment: @SiddhuSiddharthaRoy, any luck?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this please follows below link

[Step-by-Step form](http://vinceg.github.io/twitter-bootstrap-wizard/)